# how do i sort the list using all digits not just first digit in python?

Tags: python, sorting

**sorted(users, key=attrgetter('user_id'), reverse=True)[:10]**

This line is sorting the list of object based on first digit but i want all digit to consider during sort in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from operator import attrgetter

class User:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.name = x
        self.user_id = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + ":" + str(self.user_id)


users = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    data = line.strip().split('\t')
    users.append(User(data[0],data[-1]))


for user in users:
    print(user)

print('-----------')

for user in sorted(users, key=attrgetter('user_id'), reverse=True)[:10]:
    print(user)
```

Comment: Technically, since `user_id` is a `str`, it is sorting *lexicographically*.

Comment: Andhra Pradesh  154
Arunachal Pradesh  254
Assam  292
Bihar  18162
Chandigarh  12
Chhattisgarh  724
Dadra and Nagar Haveli  6
Daman and Diu  1
Delhi  644
Goa  38
Gujarat  1273
Haryana  631
Himachal Pradesh  154
Jammu and Kashmir  719
Jharkhand  923
Karnataka  1440
Kerala  1979
Lakshadweep  1
Madhya Pradesh  3220
Maharashtra  1360
Manipur  393
Meghalaya  159
Mizoram  54
Nagaland  90
Odisha  5816
Others  2
Puducherry  16
Punjab  247
Rajasthan  3846
Sikkim  2
Tamil Nadu  2441
Telangana  230
Tripura  106
Uttar Pradesh  36888
Uttarakhand  497
West Bengal  6035

Comment: input file contains things like this

Andhra Pradesh  154
Arunachal Pradesh  254
Assam  292
Bihar  18162

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to int and sorting them would help you sort using all the digits.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    data = line.strip().split('\t')
    users.append(User(data[0],int(data[-1])))
```

Comment: i think it's the opposite, need to convert to int/float

Comment: your solution gives this error

    users.append(User(data[0],int(data[-1])))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

If user_id is an integer, you should treat it as such by casting it to int. This will make the sort work as expected. Make one of these changes:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.name = x
        self.user_id = int(y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + ":" + str(self.user_id)
```

or, alternatively,

```
users = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    data = line.strip().split('\t')
    users.append(User(data[0],int(data[-1])))
```

Comment: this also gives me the same error

self.user_id = int(y)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Is your input actually separated by tabs and not spaces? Check that the value of ```data``` is what you expect.